# as3 gotoandplay frame on child movie clip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

simple one here surely..

```
mybutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, thefunction);

function thefunction(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndPlay(** frame on child movie clip **);
}
```

How do I target the frame ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call function from the child `MovieClip` entering the frame as parameter to gotoAndPlay

For example, given a symbol with instance name `childMovieClip`

```
childMovieClip.gotoAndPlay(2);
```

[image: child MovieClip instance]

[flash.display.MovieClip gotoAndPlay](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#gotoAndPlay%28%29)

Comment: that would change frame on the same timeline but there is a movieclip on that timeline within which I want a frame to be targeted to gotoandplay

Comment: & I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Then call gotoAndPlay from your child MovieClip, as in: childMovieClip.gotoAndPlay(1);